# Firefox 3.6 new tabs open skipping one spot

Tags: windows-7, firefox, firefox-3.6

I wasn't sure how to figure out what was going on here, as I'm not sure how to word it to even find a good hit on google.  Basically, it is just a minor annoyance, but I wanted to see if anyone has this same issue.

When I middle click on a link when I have a few tabs open, instead of placing the new tab to the right of the current one, it will place it to the right of the tab to the right of the current one.  I am not sure what the conditions are for this behavior, it's just weird and I wanted to see if anyone else has this issue.  I am on Windows 7 x64.

To make it clearer, here is an example

Tabs:

```
A, B, CURRENT, C, D, E,...
```

I'm in the current tab and middle click a link

Tabs:

```
A, B, CURRENT, C, NEW, D, E, ...
```

And if I click another link in current, the pattern will continue

Tabs:

```
A, B, CURRENT, C, NEW, D, NEW2, E, ...
```

Is it just me? Is there a fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a bug, but is more likely caused by a wonky extension.

Try starting Firefox in Safe Mode, by going to Start > All Programs > Mozilla Firefox > Mozilla Firefox (Safe Mode).  If it works properly there, one of the extensions you have installed is causing the problem.

If not, your profile might be corrupt.  Try creating a new profile.  Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, type in `firefox -profilemanager`, and press Enter.  Click *Create Profile*.  You can enter any name you want.  Once it's done, make sure the new profile is selected and choose *Start Firefox*.  See if the problem persists.  If not, [you can recover your information from your old profile if necessary](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Recovering%20important%20data%20from%20an%20old%20profile) and use this one.

If the problem continues, I would [report the problem to Mozilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/).

Comment: Hmm, it seemed to go away in safe mode, but I also couldn't reproduce it normally.  It's just very intermittent and I'll have to try to track it down by disabling extensions over time.